# how to get my destination latitude and longitude from mySQL to edit text in destination for maps application in android

Tags: android, maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get latitude and longitude position that stored in mySQL and use it in android map application.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303045/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-position-that-stored-in-mysql-and-use-it-in-an)

I've tried to get may latitude and longitude from mySQL database to android to use them in to maps application. I use this source :

```
Button shareit = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnDir);
        shareit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent z = getIntent();
            String des_lat = z.getStringExtra("des_lat");
            String des_long = z.getStringExtra("des_long");
            Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri 
                    .parse (String.format("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+des_lat+","+des_long)));
                    //("geo:37.827500,-122.481670"));
            startActivity(i);
            }
        }
        );
```

but the resut of my app is the edit text in maps application just filled `null,null`

how to make it `des_latitude,des_longitude`

help me please...!